# arc object has method lock from mutex as instance method

Tags: rust

I have a struct `Db`.

```
struct Db {
  entries: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>
}
impl Db {
  pub fn new() -> Db {
    Db {
      entries: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Hashmap::new()))
    }
  }
}

let db = Db::new();
db.entries.lock() // works fine returning &Result<MutexLock>
```

I am having a hard time understanding how a method `lock()` is accessible on the `Arc` object.

Per the documentation for `Arc`, `Arc<T> will implement Send and Sync as long as the T implements Send and Sync.`. `Mutex` implements `Send` and `Sync` hence `Arc` must also be implementing it. I traced the [code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#241) and found the following guard clause.

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Send for Arc<T> {}
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
unsafe impl<T: ?Sized + Sync + Send> Sync for Arc<T> {
```

What I am not understanding is how can the `.lock()` method on the `Arc` object return the `Result<MutexGuard<HashMap<...>>>`

When I hover and `ctrl + click` on the lock method it takes me to the [mutex.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sync/mutex.rs.html#263). Isn't it supposed to take me to an instance method of the `Arc` module or and some trait which was implemented in the `Arc` module? I am confused at this point. If anyone can help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arc` implements `Deref` trait which "gives" you access to the methods of the enclosed object as the if those methods were implemented on the `Arc` itself.
It's a syntactic sugar, as far as I understand.

This syntactic sugar is the reason you should use fully qualified syntax if you want to call `Arc` methods.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

let arc = Arc::new(());
// Method-call syntax
let arc2 = arc.clone();
// Fully qualified syntax
let arc3 = Arc::clone(&arc);
```

Comment: In addition to exposing the method on arc object. it also coerces the value from `Arc<Mutex<..>>` to `&Mutex<..>` as `lock()` method expects `&Mutex<..>`. This coercion is possible as both Mutex and Arc implement `Deref`. If any method from Mutex module expects `&mut Mutex<>` then also it coerces the value to `&mut` using `DerefMut` trait which is implemented by both `Arc` and `Mutex`.